# Problem in installing Ubuntu 12.04 in ASUS laptop

Tags: installation

I am facing problems in installing Ubuntu 12.04 in my ASUS A52 laptop. I selected 'Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7'. then a window appeared: Left side, there was 45.9 GB, right side it has 9.9 GB. After clicking 'install now', a window appeared named 'Write previous changes to disk and continue?' I clicked 'continue'. Then appeared the following notification:

```
Error: 'Parted can't resize partitions managed by Windows Dynamic disk'
```

Now what should I do now?

I have 7 drives in windows:

```
C: 42.7GB(7.53GB free) 
D: 25.2GB(3.24GB free) 
E: 273GB(15GB free) 
F: 70.4GB(13GB free) 
H: 10GB(1.93GB free) 
I: 24.4GB(315MB free) 
K: 9.76GB(9.68GB free)
```

I have Windows 7 installed in C drive. Is it a partioning problem?

Comment: yes its a partition problem

Comment: may i know have u installed windows already

Comment: yes. I have mentioned that. I have installed windows-7 in C drive.

Answer (score 0):

That is a partition problem that you need to fix in windows first. Open free space in your hard disk from windows to be reserved for ubuntu.
Once you have created the free space, start the installation process and choose "other option" when you get to the screen on how you want to install ubuntu.
You will be taken to the partition manager screen.
There create a partition from the free space for ubuntu installation and choose the mount point "/".
Create another partition from the free space for swap space (1 to 2 times your RAM size) and choose "swap" as partition type.
Minimum you need two partitions for ubuntu, for ubuntu installation itself and for swap. You can also create extra to have your "/home" data on a different partition then your ubuntu main installation.

Next time, use online #ubuntu channel on irc for this minor issue since it is not an error because ubuntu tries to auto resize your windows partition but you have complicated partition then a average user will have.
http://www.ubuntu.com/support/community/chat

Comment: Sorry. Of course it is not ubuntu's problem. It caused because of me. Actually I did not know about Chat. I found askubuntu and thought I can ask. next time I will remember your advice.

But, still have a problem. By going through 'other option', there shows only two partition: sda1 (ntfs) which is 55.8 GB and sda2 (unknown) which is 444.3 GB ! Why it is not showing all drives seperately? I created a new drive by 'Disk Management' but it was also not showed.

Comment: ....If i choose either sda1 or sda2, and then click 'install now', a window came : "No root file system is defined. Please correct this from the partitioning menu." Please help and then you can delete the post after it is solved.

Comment: Should'nt I comment more and go to chat?